# vertical green stripes on the screen

Tags: boot, graphics-card, mount, ubuntu-12.04

I had ubuntu installed on my laptop (Sony vaio vgn-fz470e) was working with it, suddenly it restarted and then screen showed colorful squares at first and vertical green stripes remained on the screen. then it showed me a message could not mount /tmp . and after that I restarted it again. it does not show any message. it still shows me the green stripes and just shows me the tty terminal.

Can anybody help me with the issue? what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be what was the last thing you did to the computer :)

Sometimes it is just a miss mach of screen resolution so try:

Resetting an out-of-range resolution

If you set a resolution inappropriate for your monitor in the Screen Resolution GUI tool, you can reset it from a terminal by running

```
$ rm ~/.config/monitors.xm
```

Alternatively you could:
Use the VAIO Hardware Diagnostics utility to diagnose hardware issues using the VAIO Care™ software.

http://www.kb.sony.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=C1013171&mdl=VPCF115FM

That will tell you if you have more serious problem of bad hardware.

How to:
Booting into recovery mode

```
Switch on your computer
Wait until the BIOS finishes loading (you will probably see a logo of your computer manufacturer)

The following messages may show up:

Grub loading stage1.5

Grub loading, please wait...

Quickly press the Shift key or Escape, which will bring up a boot menu. (If you see the Ubuntu logo, you've missed the point where you can enter the GRUB menu)

Select the line ending with '(recovery mode)', probably the second line, something like:

Ubuntu, kernel 2.6.17-10-generic (recovery mode)

Press enter and your machine will begin the boot process.
After a few moments, your workstation should display a menu with a number of options. One of the options (you may need to scroll down to the bottom of the list) will be "Drop to root shell prompt".
```

Comment: I'd guess since the problem is in linux, so either of these solutions might not work that well. I do believe ubuntu has a failsafe mode that would be the equivalent of windows safe mode, however.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there in my Case i Was Adjusting brightness and followed this article https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/
and when it finished i saw screen with square green stripes but then i opened terminal using **Super + T** and then just added then just removed the file i created using following Command.Don't Forget to Reboot !

```
sudo rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of submitting a temporary comment.